# Python empty csr_matrix throws ValueError: cannot infer dimensions from zero sized index arrays

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

Here's the python SSCCE:

```
import scipy.sparse
data = []
row = []
col = []
csr = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((data, (row, col)))  #error happens here
print(type(csr))
print(csr)
```

I'm running it with python2.7 I get an error:

```
raise ValueError('cannot infer dimensions from zero sized index arrays')
ValueError: cannot infer dimensions from zero sized index arrays
```

It works correctly when I feed them values like this:

```
csr = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(([10,20,30], ([0,0,0],[0,1,2])))
```

or like this:

```
csr = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(([10,20], ([0,0],[0,1])))
csr = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(([10], ([0],[0])))
```

I read the documentation at:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html and

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html#usage-information

but that doesn't seem to explain why I can't make a csr matrix with zero items in it.

What's going on with this error?  I guess scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix types must have at least one value in them on instantiation?  That seems like a silly restriction.

Answer (score 2):

Scipy sparse matrices have a definite shape, e.g. (m, n) where m is the number of rows and n is the number of columns.  When you write, for example, `csr_matrix(([1, 2], ([0, 3], [1, 4])))`, `csr_matrix` infers the shape from the maximum values of the row and column indices.  But when you write `csr_matrix(([], ([], [])))`, the function has no way of knowing what the shape of the matrix should be (and I guess it won't create a matrix with shape (0, 0) by default).

One way to handle that is to give an explicit `shape`:

```
In [241]: csr_matrix(([], ([], [])), shape=(3, 3))
Out[241]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: Really, you should probably give an explicit shape instead of letting SciPy guess even when the array isn't empty.

Comment: You can create an empty csr_matrix like this: `csr = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((0, 0))`.  However it won't infer this from an empty list.  That's the question, why must it infer something went wrong rather than that we correctly want no elements?  The answer is because that's just the way it is, deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an empty sparse matrix - from an empty dense one or by giving the shape parameter:

```
In [477]: from scipy import sparse
In [478]: sparse.csr_matrix([])
Out[478]: 
<1x0 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [479]: sparse.csr_matrix(([],([],[])),shape=(0,0))
Out[479]: 
<0x0 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

You can even create a large empty one with `shape`:

```
In [480]: sparse.csr_matrix(([],([],[])),shape=(1000,1000))
Out[480]: 
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [481]: M=_
In [482]: M[34,334]=1000
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:730: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
```

But given the inefficiency of inserting values or concatenating a new matrix, I don't see why you'd want to make such a creature.

The relevant code from `sparse.coo_matrix` when the first argument is a tuple:

```
           try:
                obj, (row, col) = arg1
            except (TypeError, ValueError):
                raise TypeError('invalid input format')

            if shape is None:
                if len(row) == 0 or len(col) == 0:
                    raise ValueError('cannot infer dimensions from zero '
                                     'sized index arrays')
                M = np.max(row) + 1
                N = np.max(col) + 1
                self.shape = (M, N)
```